# Como validar rutas en NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Estoy usando NodeJS y ExpressJS para crear un sitio web, pero me encuentro con la siguiente duda. Tengo mi archivo de rutas, donde declaro las siguientes:

```
      router.get('/', (req, res) => {
          res.render('index.ejs');
    })

      router.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
           res.render('contact.ejs');
    })
```

Yo por la URL ingreso una ruta distinta de las anteriores que tengo declaradas, es decir:

```
http://localhost:3000/prueba
```

Esto arroja el error **Cannot get /prueba**. Yo quisiera saber, como puedo hacer que en caso tal, algun usuario trata de acceder a una ruta que no esta declarada, lo redireccione a una pagina que yo decida??? Yo crearia una pagina, para darle manejo, al estilo de **la pagina que intentas acceder no existe, click aqui**

De antemano, gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quien pueda interesarle y le ocurra este mismo error, encontré una forma de solucionarlo, no se si sea la mejor, pero me funciono.

Lo que hice fue usar un midleware, el cual valida si el status es 404. En caso de ser así, redireccione a mi vista html para el manejo de estos casos (una pagina tipo, recurso no encontrado).

Adjunto imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien sabe de alguna mejor solucion, por que lo que hice es mala practica o algo, estoy atento.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Al final de todas las rutas utilizas el caracter de wildcard *

```
router.get('/*', callback())
```

Tiene que estar al final porque si lo pones antes de otra ruta, utiliza esta ruta y no las que declares después

Comment: Gracias eso estaba probando, pero me genera un error donde no me reconoce el CSS. Me genera un error acerca de MIME

Comment: Estás usando partials / headers ?

Comment: Si, estoy trabajando con ejs

Comment: sabes como se puede solucionar?